# IE problems: HTML tooltips on hover, requires a doctype

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, tooltip, doctype

I have some simple CSS/HTML for a very basic tooltip:

```
    <style type="text/css">
    .tooltip {
        text-decoration: none;
        position: relative;
    }
    .tooltip span {
        margin-left: -999em;
        position: absolute;
    }
    .tooltip:hover span {
        border-radius: 5px 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
        box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        position: absolute; left: 1em; top: 2em; z-index: 99;
        margin-left: 0; width: 250px;
    }
    .custom { padding: 0.4em 0.4em 0.4em 0.8em; }
    .info { background: #D5F1FF; border: 3px solid #2BB0D7; }
    </style>

<span class="tooltip">Thing which can be hovered on</a>
<span class="custom info">
Text in tooltip goes here...
</span></span>
```

Which works all fine for Firefox and Chrome, obviously, but when I try it with Internet Explorer, the tooltip just doesn't load/work...

HOWEVER, when I put a doctype at the top e.g:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

It works fine in Internet Explorer, but all my other layout's seem to break, i've never used a doctype, for the reasons of never needing one. Layouts been fine in all three browsers until this.

Is there something in the CSS which can be changed so the tooltip will work in Internet Explorer (without a doctype) or a similar tooltip CSS method? -Pref not javascript.

Hope i've explained my problem sufficiently, thanks.

Comment: Note: It doesn't have to be a span (the 'tooltip') if it is easier the class 'tooltip' can be instead a <a href>, thanks.

Comment: Which version if IE are you testing with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you're going to need to use a doctype in your new layouts moving forward. It's nearing the end of 2012; having a doctype is pretty much required these days. For one, it ensures consistency between browsers: as you may have seen, the quirks modes of other browsers is similar to their standards modes... and vastly different from IE's own quirks mode.

That said, you *can* use an `<a href>` in place of a `<span>` if you must adhere to quirks mode for whatever reason, and `:hover` will work in IE just fine:

```
<a href="#" class="tooltip">Thing which can be hovered on</a>
```

Comment: One thing to highlight here, including a non-blank href property triggers some version of IE to treat the anchor *as an anchor*.

Comment: @svidgen: You mean like `<a name="anchor">`?

Comment: Thanks works fine. I'll see if I can work in a doctype in the future though, thanks for advice.

Comment: @BoltClock Nope. I mean the **href** attribute itself, just like you have it. Just wanted to draw attention to the fact that the href="#" is important to have in there.